# Django 1.3 with Webassets 0.7: assets.py ignored?

Tags: django

I'm trying to get an existing Django project to work on my mac.
I managed to configure everything and opening the project in PyCharm.

When I run I get the error:

TemplateSyntaxError at /
Caught BundleError while rendering: 'stylesheets' not found (using staticfiles finders)

We use Django 1.3 and Webassets 0.7 (just updated from earlier versions).
I have an assets.py defined in my application folder defining the various bundles.

Any suggestions on solving this?

**EDIT:** Ok, a bit further ... I added my project.assest to settings and now I don't have the Bundle error. I do still have another problem:
*Caught BundleError while rendering: 'styles/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css' not found*

Path look ok, collectstatic works, copies, file is in place ...

any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a problem specific to your Webassets app (which I haven't used)? Are you testing this with the dev server? If so, collectstatic isnt relevant if you are letting django serve them dev style

Comment: indeed, not relevant, I am doing this on a dev server. The only problem that resists is the FileNotFound part. All files are in place and still WebAssets gives a file not found when serving :-S

Answer (score 2):

A project-wide `assets.py` (as opposed to one in an app-directory) is no longer automatically read, you need to define such files through a `ASSETS_MODULES` setting now.

If you are using staticfiles, pay attention to the fact that the staticfile finders will not be used unless Django is in debug mode (settings.DEBUG=True). In production mode, webassets will assume that collectstatic has been run first.

In settings.DEBUG=True mode, the reverse is true: ONLY the Django staticfile finders will be used. You could try opening a shell (`./manage.py shell`) and see if the following finds your file:

```
 from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
 finders.find('styles/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css')
```

If it does, then so should webassets.

Comment: seems it is solved by adding  
'django_assets.finders.AssetsFinder'
in STATICFILES_FINDERS

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error arise

```
'[BUNDLE_NAME]' not found (using staticfiles finders)
```

This wasn't a very helpful message, so ended up looking into `./manage.py shell` and running

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> from [ASSETS_FILE_PATH.assets] import [BUNDLE_NAME]
>>> [BUNDLE_NAME]
```

If this isn't there it may give you another message.